# Superior label in chemfomula's arrow doesn't accept a word after an element

Tags: chemformula

I have to write a simple reaction using `chemformula` with a double arrow (`\ch{<=>}`) and a label above the arrow. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

    \ch{A + B <=>[ H+ ] C + D}

\end{document}
```

The problem comes when I try to insert a word after the hydrogen, let's say *heat*:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

    \ch{A + B <=>[ H+ ,~heat] C + D}

\end{document}
```

gives an error of extra/missing `}`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the space before the closing bracket. Spaces are important in chemformula:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

    \ch{A + B <=>[ H+ ,~heat ] C + D}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I completely forgot that space: thanks a lot!